# Realm.io offline, Parse online - What about users

Tags: android, parse-platform, realm

I'm using Parse for the first time to play around with.
I use Realm.io as a offline db.
Both are very powerful and it's great to get to know them better.
(Big up to both teams!)

My app should be able to be used on remote locations, where you can't get data from Parse. I want to be able to rely on Realm in these situations.

I just implemented user management in Parse, but I don't know what would be the best way to reflect this with realm. Should I create a User object in realm and make a one to one relation with all my models. Should I save the username as a property in the models?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also tried the combination of Realm and Parse. And yes you'll have to sync the data manually between both datasets by creating models for each.

But I think writing (almost) the same model classes for both Parse and Realm could be counter-productive. That's why I dropped Realm and used Parse LocalDataStore instead. By using localDataStore, you still would have to write the sync logic yourself but the code would be cleaner (in my opinion).

Another option is to go for [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com). Firebase handles the sync logic itself so you don't have to and it even gives you real-time sync. So I would highly recommend you check that out. But Firebase doesn't have Push Notifications. For that you can still use Parse.

Hope this helps.

**Update**

Firebase now offers push notifications as well. (and Parse has been discontinued)

Comment: Now Firebase have Push Notifications feature